# Bendy Bones Stretch to Constrain Rotation Issue

Tags: rigging

I am trying to get stretch to constraint to work with the end handle set to absolute when the parent bone is flipped and it's causing some weird rotational glitches.

I've attached a screenshot of the issue, the modifier, and the handle settings. I've duplicated the bone and set it to octahedral so you can easier see the direction of the bones.

I want it to follow it with absolute behavior as it normally would if the bone wasn't flipped. Any simple solutions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're stretching to the head of the bone, which you probably don't want, and which affects the bendy bones.  If you don't scale it to overlong, Blender does what you probably want (maybe it has some special handling for that case.)

However, the general solution for this kind of problem is: make another bone that does have the axes you want, and parent it to the bone that doesn't:

[image]